# Insert date created in converted file

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet, xlsx

I have script and currently working but I need to modify it to add date stamp when the file converted and move to another folder, let me know what I need to modify/change on my script to apply the needed process?

Script

```
const tempFile = Drive.Files.insert(
          {title: "PROJECT_CO_", parents: [{"id": tempFolder}]},
          excel.getBlob(),
          {convert: true}
        );
```

My plan is to have name format like **PROJECT_CO_[DATE].xlsx**

Answer (score 1):

### Using Javascript Type Objects

```
const now = new Date();
```

By Using this you can get current date and you can concatenate this date with your file name and save.

### Extra Tips

If you are facing issues such as time zone then you can change timezone from settings or refer to this [article](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/58515?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&oco=0#zippy=%2Cchange-locale-and-time-zone) for more help.